# Cannot install odoo using source installation method : ImportError: cannot import name fp_str

Tags: python, node.js, centos, odoo

I need to run multiple instances of odoo on my centos 7 server. So i needto use source insallation method for installing to install odoo as written in their documentation.

I was able to install odoo (git clonning to my system, installing dependencies, installing less css using npm) everything works fine for me till here.

After that they say i have to start running odoo using odoo.py script file as shown in the code sample below:

```
`./odoo.py -w <my_postgres_password> -r <postgres_user> --addons-path=addons,../mymodules --db-filter=mydb$`
```

But here i get into an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./odoo.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "./odoo.py", line 156, in main
    import openerp
  File "/home/odoo1/odoo/openerp/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    import report
  File "/home/odoo1/odoo/openerp/report/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import interface
  File "/home/odoo1/odoo/openerp/report/interface.py", line 13, in <module>
    import render
  File "/home/odoo1/odoo/openerp/report/render/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from simple import simple
  File "/home/odoo1/odoo/openerp/report/render/simple.py", line 9, in <module>
    from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Table
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from reportlab.platypus.flowables import Flowable, Image, Macro, PageBreak, Preformatted, Spacer, XBox, \
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py", line 29, in <module>
    from reportlab.lib.colors import red, gray, lightgrey
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/colors.py", line 17, in <module>
    from reportlab.lib.utils import fp_str
ImportError: cannot import name fp_str
```

What can be the error due to. How to solve this issue?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `from reportlab.lib.rl_accel import fp_str` in the newest version of reportlab.So you need to upgrade the reportlab module.